# Extending Android SearchView

Tags: android, search, searchview, extend

I have a custom Android SearchView in my application. I am trying to extend it by adding custom icons-camera for ImageSearch functionality.

I have tried to extend it by using onCreateActionMode of its searchTextView s, but, the icon is not showing up. I want the icon to be added inside by SearchView. Here is my code :

```
public class CabSearchView extends SearchView {
private static final boolean DEFAULT_CAB_ENABLED = true;
private static final int IMAGESEARCH = 0;

private boolean mCabEnabled;

public CabSearchView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CabSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.searchViewStyle);
}

public CabSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    int themedIconColor = R.color.white;
    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchSrcTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    searchSrcTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback());
    searchSrcTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(themedIconColor));
    searchSrcTextView.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(themedIconColor));
    ImageView searchMagIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchMagIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(themedIconColor));
    ImageView searchCloseBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchCloseBtn.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(themedIconColor));
    addFilter(searchSrcTextView, new PlainTextInputFilter());

    initLayoutAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public boolean isCabEnabled() {
    return mCabEnabled;
}

public void setCabEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mCabEnabled = enabled;
}

private void addFilter(TextView textView, InputFilter filter) {
    InputFilter[] filters = textView.getFilters();
    InputFilter[] newFilters = Arrays.copyOf(filters, filters.length + 1);
    newFilters[filters.length] = filter;
    textView.setFilters(newFilters);
}

private void initLayoutAttributes(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    TypedArray attrsArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CabSearchView, defStyleAttr, 0);

    setCabEnabled(attrsArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CabSearchView_cabEnabled,
            DEFAULT_CAB_ENABLED));

    attrsArray.recycle();
}

private class Callback implements ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, IMAGESEARCH, 0, 
  "ImageSearch").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_camera_white_24dp);
        return isCabEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) { }
}

private static class PlainTextInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest,
                               int dstart, int dend) {
        return RichTextUtil.stripRichText(source, start, end).subSequence(start, end);
    }
}
}
```

In other case, I tried this :

```
ImageView camImageView = new ImageView(this.fragment.getActivity());
camImageView .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera_white_24dp);
((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0)).addView(camImageView,0);
```

In this case, the image is showing up at the extreme left of the actual searchView.

I expected the icon to be included in the searchTextview before the close button, but, it is either not showing up or showing at the extreme left or right depending upon its placement as a child view of the searchTextView.

---

**Expected**

[image: Expected Image]

---

**Current**

[image: Current Result]

Comment: Add the expected view and current view images, so that will be easy to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: I have edited the question with pictures, please check.

Comment: Instead of this ((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0)).addView(camImageView,0); First get the total child count and then use     ((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(total_child - 1)).addView(camImageView,0); I guess this should work.

Comment: @Simplyprogrammer, it's not working.

Comment: Are u getting any error, or the output is not as expected.

Comment: No, it is showing the "Current" screen as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple Search View, it should work with your Search View class as well.

Below is the code.

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);

ImageView camImageView = new ImageView(this);
camImageView .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
int getTotalChild = searchView.getChildCount();
((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(getTotalChild-1)).addView(camImageView);
```

In your case the index should be `getTotalChild - 2` for the last line in the code.
It should work.

Comment: Check this line `((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(getTotalChild-1)).addView(camImageView);` I have not used index for `addView`.